# can you not compress CSS but work on it later?

Tags: css, compression, minify

I've even looked at CSS Crush, Minify, SmartOptimizer, CSSTidy and a slew of other PHP CSS compressors.  But they all have one major flaw.

You can't use this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

When using dreamweaver, this is the only way to see the DESIGN in DESIGN VIEW.  If you replace that `styles.css` file with `styles.php`, it breaks, even if you HAVE css code in the file..

I am using minify for my JS and it is working beautifully, but if I use it with CSS, Dreamweaver gets scared and doesn't know how to render it. haha.  Of course, it IS server side though.

Does anybody have a workaround for a situation like this? I do prefer to use dreamweaver because of the immediate changes that can be made in design view, as well as the FTP capabilities and code hinting, but even the new CS6 seems to whine when you use anything BUT a `.css` file.

Comment: Minification should be part of build process. so in the development environment you can use regular CSS and JS file but when you deploy it to server you can Minifiy them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't verify that this solution will work, but it should theoretically.

First, you'll want to add `.css` files *as* PHP, so you don't have to change the file extension. This is good practice regardless, since the file extension should indicate what content is being delivered. I don't know that there's any standard that states this outright, but it's good practice. If you're using Apache, you can add this to your `.htaccess` or global server configuration file:

```
AddHandler php5-script .css
```

Then, just `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />` after renaming your file back to CSS. For more details on this, see the Apache docs on [`AddHandler`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler).

Second, you'll want to 'comment out' your PHP code within your CSS. For example, you could do something like this at the top of `style.css`:

```
/*
    <?php include 'your-file-compressor.php'
    // Put any PHP code for compression here
    ?>
*/
```

That way, Dreamweaver will still read the actual CSS code, but PHP should be able to compress before delivering it to clients.

Comment: Very interesting!!! I didnt even think about AddHandler. Lemme give that a try and I'll report back.

Comment: Hmm doesnt seem like that wanted to play too nicely. Commented or uncommented, the php code is not running, it doesn't seem. http://dev.paulhanak.com/css/styles.css

Comment: Is your server Apache-based? That AddHandler thing only works on Apache servers, and only some at that. However, it should be possible to do something very similar on *any* server.

Comment: Oh yes, it is Apache. And I have used the AddHandler before for .html pages to run .php.

Comment: That's strange that it doesn't work, in that case. Have you tried adding it to your global config, or restarting your server?

Comment: Ah HA! I had to use "RemoveHandler .css" "AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .css" to get her working.  Beauuutiful! Thank you for the help and thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

As Kishore pointed out, Minificaiton should be part of build process. While development you should use the raw css file.

Instead of `href="css/styles.php"` its better to use `href="compresscss/path/css/styles.css"`.  Here `compresscss/path/css/styles.css` is mapped to `compresscss.php?path=css/style.css`. This can be done by `mod_rewrite` in apache.

This way dreamweaver will see it as an css file and also you will compress it.

Comment: I definatly understand your thoughts on this.  I was also thinking about the build process. However, if I am using href="compresscss/path/css/styles.css" then that means I will not see any of the changes in Dreamweaver WHILE I am working on it since that is linking to the AFTER built css, yes?